# Access-Control-Allow-Origin on chrome extension

Tags: php, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm making a Chrome extension which pulls data from my own server. It uses about 4 httpRequests at a time, but sometimes I get console error as follows:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://apps.radionsm.lv/apps/system/index.php?request=now. Origin chrome-extension://egkddfmbidfobhchndockbhjancbpfkd is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` for everyone sometimes no.

If I send `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` will this fix it?

Answer (score 38):

You're trying to do cross origin resource sharing (CORS). The bad news is that without a server as a middle man there is no way to do this on a normal web page. The good news is that in a chrome extension you can request permission to access any url's you want. Just put something like this in your manifest.json file.

Allow connections to your site:

```
 "permissions": [
    "http://*.radionsm.lv/"
  ],
```

Allow connections to any site:

```
 "permissions": [
    "http://*/"
  ],
```

When the user installs your extension chrome will inform them of the permissions required in a dialogue box prior to the completion of the install.

Comment: Worth mentioning - I had to delete and re-install the extension in order for the permissions to be updated from the manifest file.

Comment: I upvoted Geva Tal's comment here, and want to further emphasize that you really have to uninstall your extension and then reinstall it. Just reloading the extension from within Chrome doesn't suffice.

Comment: It works, but you cannot use wildcards like that.... it has to be specific subdomains

Comment: @MartinZvarík: the [official docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/match_patterns/) beg to differ. You can use `https://*/*` and even `<all_urls>` :)

Comment: Manifest V3 requires you to list all URLs in the new `"host_permissions": []` field!

Answer (score 26):

Chrome Extensions have two "modes" when making cross-domain XHR requests:

1) If the domain is in the "permissions" section of the manifest.json file - The request doesn't have an "Origin" header, and it always succeeds.

2) If the domain is not in "permissions" - The request includes an "Origin" header with the value "chrome-extension://..." This indicates that the request is a CORS request, and the response must have a valid Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in order to succeed.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to set up permissions in manifest.json:

```
  "permissions": [
    "https://example.com/" // if you need a particular site
    "<all_urls>"           // if you need any site (this will incur 
                           // manual review process in Chrome web store, mind you)
  ],
```

Please note, that since Chrome 85 extn content scripts are [subject to the same CORS policy](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches) as vanilla web requests. Which means that **the only way to do cross-site requests in extn now is to fetch in background script and pass the result to content script**:

```
// Old content script, making a cross-origin fetch:
var itemId = 12345;
var url = "https://another-site.com/price-query?itemId=" +
         encodeURIComponent(request.itemId);
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(text => parsePrice(text))
  .then(price => ...)
  .catch(error => ...)

// New content script, asking its background page to fetch the data instead:
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
    {contentScriptQuery: "queryPrice", itemId: 12345},
    price => ...);

// New extension background page, fetching from a known URL and relaying data:
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.contentScriptQuery === "queryPrice") {
      var url = "https://another-site.com/price-query?itemId=" +
              encodeURIComponent(request.itemId);
      fetch(url)
          .then(response => response.text())
          .then(text => parsePrice(text))
          .then(price => sendResponse(price))
          .catch(error => ...)
      return true;  // Will respond asynchronously.
    }
  });
```

Comment: Can you please update your answer with actual info? I have similar issue and I've specified my domain in host_permissions in my mv3 like "https://*.domain.com/*" and it works for cross domain request from any website to domain.com via background worker in my development version of extension but it WONT work in submitted extension installed from chrome store. Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

**Manifest V3:** change `permissions` to `host_permissions`:

```js
"host_permissions": [
  "http://*/"
],
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending days on google, finally the solution which worked out for me is this.

1. If you are using Spring boot and you are writing your own CORSFilter class also you are maintaining security java configuration file dont ever write multiple CORS to register in spring.

In my case I had CORSFilter java class as well as below code.
`http.cors(withDefaults())`
// removed this since I already registered CORS.

Comment: Ok, I'll check it.