# "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Tags: google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I already tried looking for various questions, but that didn't help/I am too inexperienced to understand, so I have to be specific.
This is what I get in the console:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://a.websight.com/file/hex.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'chrome-extension://asdfghetcetcetc' is therefore not allowed access. (index):1

It's breaking my entire extension and I don't know how to fix it. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access-Control-Allow-Origin on chrome extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056156/access-control-allow-origin-on-chrome-extension)

Comment: Thank you, rsanchez, adding a global permission worked!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest in chrome extensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421933/cross-origin-xmlhttprequest-in-chrome-extensions)

Answer (score 37):

Although question is quite old, I found that google developer site provide easy way to remember global kind of permission. If you want to make cross origin ajax requests in any where you can add `"permissions": ["<all_urls>"]` to the manifest. Or else you can use matching patterns which are described in [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns).

Comment: I was having the same problem and this solves the issue. Thank you.

Comment: In Manifest V3 you have to use `"host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"]`