# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to pull some data from an API for my chrome extension and I keep getting this error:

```
Failed to load http://search.mtvnservices.com/typeahead/suggest/?solrformat=true&rows=20&callback=noCB&q=*%3A*+AND+schoolid_s%3A1255+AND+teacherdepartment_s%3A%22Chemistry%22&defType=edismax&qf=teacherfirstname_t%5E2000+teacherlastname_t%5E2000+teacherfullname_t%5E2000+autosuggest&bf=pow(total_number_of_ratings_i%2C2.1)&sort=total_number_of_ratings_i+desc&siteName=rmp&rows=20&start=0&fl=pk_id+teacherfirstname_t+teacherlastname_t+total_number_of_ratings_i+averageratingscore_rf+schoolid_s&fq=: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'chrome-extension://cfibejgbiljlkoanlanaenhdgjpfmief' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I've downloaded the CORS chrome extension, to no avail. What do I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20155283/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

Comment: I believe a solution is posted already here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20155283/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource