# Adding Instagram into Tweetdeck

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, twitter, google-chrome-extension, instagram-api

I finally got fed up with Tweetdeck and the inability for it to load images from Instagram. So i've decided to solve the problem using a Chrome Extension. It's quite a difficult thing to do since Tweetdeck has very strict content security policies. However I have found a work around.

Using the [Instagram embedding code](https://instagram.com/developer/embedding/) we can extract the ID of the image and form a new image based on the ID. This is a link to a 301 redirect to the actual image. However when I try and run this on Tweetdeck a random transparent .png appears. Which forces this error:

```
Refused to load the image 'http://images.instagram.com/transparent.gif' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src https: data:".
```

I can't seem to find where this png is coming from, it's not being loaded by my app, nor instagram. It is breaking everything else and causing the 301 redirect to be cancelled.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Manifest

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Instagram for TweetDeck",
  "description": "This extension will show thumbnails for instagram on TweetDeck",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; img-src http: https: data:",
  "content_scripts": [
     {
       "matches": ["https://tweetdeck.twitter.com/"],
       "js": ["instagram_tweetdeck.js"]
     }
  ]
}
```

JS File

```
var func = function () {

var Instagram = function () {
    this.links = [];
};

Instagram.prototype.add = function (url, element) {

    if (this.links.indexOf(url) !== -1) {
        // already done this link
        return;
    }
    this.links.push(url);

    var id = url.substr(url.indexOf('/p/')).replace('/p/', '').replace('/', '');

    obj = document.createElement('img');
    obj.src = 'https://instagram.com/p/' + id + '/media/?size=m';
    obj.width = "230";
    obj.style.marginTop = "10px";
    element.parentNode.insertBefore(obj, element);
};


var instagram = new Instagram();

var poll = function () {
    var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        if (nodes[i].innerHTML.indexOf('instagram.com') !== -1) {
            instagram.add(nodes[i].innerHTML, nodes[i]);
        }
    }
};

setInterval(poll, 500);
};

var script = document.createElement("script");
script.textContent = "(" + func.toString() + ")();";
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add in your `manifest.json`:

```
"permissions": [
    "*://*.instagram.com",
    "*://*.twitter.com"
],
```

From the Chrome Extension documentation of [XHR](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr):

> #### Requesting cross-origin permissions
>
> By adding hosts or host match patterns (or both) to the permissions section of the manifest file, the extension can request access to remote servers outside of its origin.

#### Useful links

- [Declare permissions - Chrome Extension docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions)
- [Match patterns - Chrome Extension docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns)
- [XHR - Chrome Exntension docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr)

Edit: Make sure scripts are executed in the correct way see [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#interactions) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks @dgil however the tweetdeck webpage enforces quite a script content security policy and the manifest doesn't override that, does it?

Comment: @dtsn yes, it does. The chrome extension's manifest allows you to override the settings for the page. Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9776660/1776889

Comment: @dtsn I've updated my answer to add the link to the documentation where CORS permissions is explained.

Comment: even with the updated manifest I get the same error: Refused to load the image 'http://images.instagram.com/transparent.gif' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src https: data:".

Comment: @dtsn I forgot to add `*.twitter.com` in the `manifest.json`. Can you try it?

Comment: BTW I'm not sure you need the `content_security_policy` if you add both sites in the `permissions`.

Comment: `content_security_policy` does not affect content scripts. See [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#interactions) for an explanation.

Comment: thanks @xan that example fixed the problem, I was incorrect adding the script into the body