# Postman: request failing with CORS:ORIGIN_NOT_ALLOWED

Tags: postman

I am trying to access API with a POST request, but it's failing with an error. How do I resolve it?

```json
{
  "code": 403,
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "description": "The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.",
  "message": "CORS:ORIGIN_NOT_ALLOWED:chrome-extension://aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo"
}
```

Comment: Which version of postman do you use? What is actual HTTP code of the response? Normally, 403 means you’re authenticated, but do not have access right to access. This’s basically not postman problem.

Comment: Thanks for replying back Lucas. I am using version 8.12.4 . I am able to access API from chrome , but not using Postman

Comment: This might solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056156/access-control-allow-origin-on-chrome-extension