# Protect AWS API Gateway To Only My Extension Calling It

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, manifest

Is it a possibility to setup something like the API Gateway CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin to only allow a Firefox extension that I am writing to call it? Setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin to '*' is what I did for testing, but does not seem like a good policy for when it is released.

I wondered if there was anyway to make it so the AWS API Gateway only gives a good response when the request is made by my extension, and not another. Or is this just an impossibility to restrict the API to only my extension?

I am using XMLHttpRequest to make the call to the API Gateway

Comment: I am going to try what I have foud in this stackoverflow topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056156/access-control-allow-origin-on-chrome-extension

I think this may work: 2) If the domain is not in "permissions" - The request includes an "Origin" header with the value "chrome-extension://..." This indicates that the request is a CORS request, and the response must have a valid Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in order to succeed. WWW - I am going to see what header by request has for the value "chrome-extension://..." and then put that in my AWS API Gateway CORS policy

Comment: I believe the best answer is the one that explains CORS. I did follow up research and see that the I am not able to lock down the API like I imagined using the CORS allow-origin to only allow something like chrome-extension://my-extension-name. From what I can tell this is not possible, and using a * allow-origin in my CORS may be alright to do since none of the data is private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a note; CORS is for *browsers* to restrict cross-origin HTTP requests. CORS won't stop someone invoking the API from outside a browser e.g. using cURL, Postman, or some other non-browser based app.

Comment: Close, but don't conflate the Same-Origin Policy (a set of restrictions) with CORS (a mechanism for relaxing some of those restrictions).

Comment: I have noticed this during my development. Calls that provide 200 responses in my non-browser app (Python IDE), would be rejected when I put the same call in my AWS Lambda function.